# is there any XSLT equivalent for avro payload

Tags: java, xslt, avro

I'm trying to transform a payload from avro schema `purchase-order` to another payload of the schema `invoice`.
When I was working with XML, I remember we can do this easily using XSLT. is there any XSLT equivalent for avro? I'm still unable to find such a library for Java. Can anybody point me to a direction how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no equivalent of XSLT for Avro. I'm not sure the concept even makes sense for Avro, given that it's schema-based.

Comment: @jonhanson XML is also schema based (XSD) just like avro, and it does have transformation concept, hence, XSLT

Comment: Schemas are optional with XML and are primarily for validation - you can still read the XML without the schema. With Avro you typically require the schema to be able to read the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.